# Center labels and textarea in HTML?

Tags: html, label, textarea, center

So I'm working on a site, but in run in to a little problem with centering my labels and textarea,

This is the css for the code:

```
.formWrapper {
Display: block;
Width: 550px;
Border: solid 5px #F1F1F1;
Margin-top: 100px;
Margin-right: auto;
Margin-bottom: 0;
Margin-left: auto;
Background-color: #AFC8DE;
Text-align: center;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the piece of HTML that is used and try creating a snippet or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see whats wrong and what has to be done.

Comment: please add html code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out! Sorry